# How to use util class which serves based on user information

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

This is my first posting, glad to be here.

I am developing a web application, i have a one FormateUserLanguage util class in util package i want to initialize this util class with user specific information at the stating of the application and use that instance through out the  user session(session is not available for this FormateUserLanguage class as it is util class).

example :

when userA login into the application userA information is initialized to util class and he can get the formated information for some areas.
as as userB, userC....etc,.

As this is multi user application need to show the userspecific information using FormateUserLanguage  util class.

please help out how to  implement this functionality in my application.

eagerly waiting for your reply. :)

Comment: i am using internationalization by default, if a US person want to select able to select his/her language to chines in my application based on that some areas of my application should show in chines language and chines currency and chines time stamp date.

Comment: OK - I read too much into that class name.  :P

Comment: the above util class it don't have access to session object. i want to initialize this util class only once while login and want to get that instance throughout  application. here every user need to have his own instance of that util class how to achieve this.

please help me

Answer (score 1):

I think you're thinking about an [HttpSession](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html) which you can store arbitrary objects (attributes) which can be created/retrieved by the [RequestObject](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getSession%28boolean%29).

You'll want to read up on lifecycles of web applications, and persisting such preferences. (Sessions are typically per Server JVM, but there are ways of transferring / sharing sessions between servers in a cluster)

You may want to figure out if you even need a per-session object, or if it could be created on a per-request basis with maybe with a [Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html)...

Comment: thanks for your reply, but i know the lifecycles of web application but. my util classes are not under web-inf class those are exists external jar i want to initialize once for each user and throughout user session.

Comment: The physical location of classes doesn't matter. What matters is your web application wants to use them, therefore you put them on the classpath of your web app. The servlet container gives you the Request Object which you can use to make a Session object, and store any arbitrary other object including your util class. Lifecycles and per-request were just things to look into as they might affect what you do. (I was going to suggest using a `ServletContextListener` until I realized you were wanting per user)